# Unable import Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I try to import scrapy but I have a error in import "Unable to import scrapy"
I ve installed scrapy pip and python, I added a Json decoded, before that the code runs.

```
# import sys
# reload(sys)
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from mercado.items import MercadoItem
from PIL import Image



class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercado'
    item_count = 0
    allowed_domain = ['https://www.qdq.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.qdq.com/search?location=Madrid%20%28provincia%29&query=clinicas%20dentales&ine_code=28000000000&latitude=40.4950678634&longitude=-3.7169852555&kind=P&province=Madrid&page=1']

    rules = {
        # Para cada item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[8]/@href'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//a[@class="business-card-link"]')),
            callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()
        #info de producto
        ml_item['nombre'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
        ml_item['web'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/a/@href').extract()
        script_data = response.xpath('string(/html/head/script[3]/text()').extract()
        decoded_data = json.loads(script_data)
        ml_item['datos'] = decoded_data["telephone"]
        ml_item['direccion'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()

        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count > 5:
            raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield ml_item
```

Any error in json dcoded? I need extract info for this script and I don't know any other way

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: What happens if you re-install Scrapy? Are you using a virtual environment? Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my shell and my IDE / editor are using a different python version. I suggest to check whether scrapy is installed in the right python (or virtual environment) you are using to execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use a virtual environments so that you do not mess up with packages.

Install virtual environment

> sudo pip install virtualenv

Create your project folder

> mkdir myproject
>
> cd myproject

create virtual env inside your project folder

> virtualenv -p /path/to/your/python venv

Ex: virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv

Activate virtual env

> source venv/bin/activate

Now go on installing all the libraries you want after activating.
Ex pip3 install scrapy.